# Multiple library projects in aide?

Tags: android, aide-ide

I am trying to work on my android app from my phone and tablet using Aide. I keep getting hundreds of errors.  It seems as if it is only detecting one library project at a time.  I can change which errors I get by removing a library and adding a different one (I am using three)

Has anyone successfully used multiple project libraries in aide, and might be able to offer some assistance?

My project . properties looks like this:

```
[Eclipse references (I think)]
android.library.reference.1=../../../../libraries/android-greendroid/GreenDroid
android.library.reference.2=../../../../libraries/ActionBarSherlock/library

[Aide references]
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-actionbarsherlock/library
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-facebook/facebook
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-greendroid/GreenDroid
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-actionbarsherlock/library
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/myproject/android/free
```

So, the aide references are all .1 and there are no new lines between them.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and fix this formating references like in eclipse.

Like this:

```
[Eclipse references]
android.library.reference.1=../../../../libraries/android-greendroid/GreenDroid       
android.library.reference.2=../../../../libraries/ActionBarSherlock/library

[Aide references]
android.library.reference.1=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-actionbarsherlock/library
android.library.reference.2=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-facebook/facebook
android.library.reference.3=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-greendroid/GreenDroid
android.library.reference.4=/storage/extSdCard/code/android-actionbarsherlock/library
android.library.reference.5=/storage/extSdCard/code/myproject/android/free
```

You can't edit project.properties in AIDE, so use text edit and fix this. Put enter in right place and fix reference number ;)